# RESOURCES qrc pendant for CMake?

Tags: resources, cmake, qt5, qmake

I have a Qt-Application project where the *.pro Project file contained:

> RESOURCES += icons.qrc

I got rid of my Qt-project file *.pro and start using CMakeList.txt instead.

What would be the CMake pendant for RESOURCES to use my icons and pictures there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp Icons.qrc)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autorcc